# cannot implement rest webservice in android app

Tags: android, web-services, rest

I want to implement rest webservice in android application
to do that
I create the class from this tutorial: [here](http://aryo.lecture.ub.ac.id/android-rest-http-get-example/)

but when I clcok on the matched button I have the error

```
unfortunetly, android app has stopped
```

I don't have anything in the Logcat
then I canno't know from which is the problem

here is the event code:

```
case R.id.btn_rest_test :
        Log.d("method event get", "execite :)");
        Rest r = new Rest();
        r.get("http://www.cheesejedi.com/rest_services/get_big_cheese.php?puzzle=1");
        r.getResponseString();
        EditText etdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rest_text);
        EditText etdit2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rest_error_text);
        etdit.setText(r.getResponseText());
        etdit2.setText(r.getError());
        break;
```

how can I achieve that

Comment: Likely http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: It looks like you are executing this Request on the Main thread.  This may work on pre-Honeycoumb  but on the later android OS will throw a NetworkOnMainThreadException as @laalto is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to a lot of errors.

Are you sure it does not crash because of your two EditTexts not being found?
etdit.setText would cause NullPointerExceptions.

Comment: the problem is the Logcat is empty, nothing

Answer (score 0):

Did u try to check the response Its something like this:

[{"id":"755","level":"1","time_in_secs":"3","par":"0","initials":"KiB","quote":"Got'cha!","time_stamp":"2012-04-09 22:50:52"},{"id":"977","level":"1","time_in_secs":"3","par":"0","initials":"WJF","quote":"dats right numero uno","time_stamp":"2013-03-11 02:29:36"},{"id":"874","level":"1","time_in_secs":"3","par":"0","initials":"WJF","quote":"Look, Ma. No hands!","time_stamp":"2012-05-25 15:44:10"},{"id":"59","level":"1","time_in_secs":"4","par":"0","initials":"TMF","quote":"Hey hey ole ' hickery","time_stamp":"2012-03-03 04:36:15"},{"id":"61","level":"1","time_in_secs":"4","par":"0","initials":"WJF","quote":"I'm on a boat!","time_stamp":"2012-03-03 04:38:54"}]

As you can see its not **ResponseString its a ResponseArray**. Modify it accordingly.

Also check whether it type is POST or GET

Comment: I also followed this tuto and implement it but I stay waiting for finish request at forever

Comment: is the url that you are using and the one that has been shown in the example the same ??

Comment: sorry, I forgot to show you the link of the second tuto that I tested, here is : http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/calling-restful-services-from-your-android-app/1076

Comment: the first comment is about this second tuto, no error but I stay waiting forever

Comment: did u download the full project and tried it... Is it possible that u reset your adb and check whether the u can see the log values

Comment: i u still can't see the log then check all messages.Some info is required before i can comment as to what is going wrong

Comment: I restared eclipse an then the logcat will work here is the error : android.os.networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: I just downloded the project it works well, but inside my app it doen't work

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38551/discussion-between-terril-thomas-and-begipass)

Comment: did u finally find the solution